# Can I go directly to the implementation of a method that implements an interface method from where that method is called?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

When I Alt+F12 from a call in a Controller, it takes me to the interface declaration of that method:

[image]

I would like to instead, or alternatively, go to the Repository's method, where that interface method is implemented. I realize that there could be multiple methods that implements, but if there is only one it could take you there, and if there are multiple, it could give you a list to choose from.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have "goto implementation" on my right click. Probably from resharper. Does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Pretty much; but it doesn't open it in a "peek definition" window atop the other, it takes you directly to it. Good enough, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the ReSharper plugin.

Here is the site:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Technically you have to _buy_ the ReSharper plugin first :)

Comment: yeah, its isn't free haha. But you can crack. haha (not recommended.)

Comment: the shurtcut is alt-end, along with alt-f12 one of my most used shortcuts